# WordPress hooks/filters insert before content or after title

Tags: filters, hooks

trying to insert content before the post content in my functions.php - I know how to use the regular wp hooks, but unsure how to insert into other areas.

Tried this, but it kills content on any other post type:

```
function property_slideshow( $content ) {
 if ( is_single() && 'property' == get_post_type() ) {
    $custom_content = '[portfolio_slideshow]';
    $custom_content .= $content;
    return $custom_content;
    } 
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'property_slideshow' );
```

How do I make this conditional?

Comment: In this case: just make sure your function returns $content anyway (when unmodified).

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Just use the `the_content` filter, e.g.:

```
<?php
function theme_slug_filter_the_content( $content ) {
    $custom_content = 'YOUR CONTENT GOES HERE';
    $custom_content .= $content;
    return $custom_content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'theme_slug_filter_the_content' );
?>
```

Basically, you append the post content *after* your custom content, then return the result.

#### Edit

As Franky @bueltge points out in his comment, the process is the same for the post title; simply add a filter to the `the_title` hook:

```
<?php
function theme_slug_filter_the_title( $title ) {
    $custom_title = 'YOUR CONTENT GOES HERE';
    $title .= $custom_title;
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'theme_slug_filter_the_title' );
?>
```

Note that, in this case, you append your custom content *after* the Title. (It doesn't matter which; I just went with what you specified in your question.)

#### Edit 2

The reason your example code isn't working is because you *only return `$content` when your conditional is met*. You need to return `$content`, unmodified, as an `else` to your conditional. e.g.:

```
function property_slideshow( $content ) {
    if ( is_single() && 'property' == get_post_type() ) {
        $custom_content = '[portfolio_slideshow]';
        $custom_content .= $content;
        return $custom_content;
    } else {
        return $content;
    }
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'property_slideshow' );
```

This way, for posts not of the 'property' post-type, `$content` is returned, un-modified.

Comment: also it is possible to add content after title; the filter the_title is the right hook.

Comment: @ChipBennett question - how to do this with logic only for a custom post type - I tried to wrap it in `if ( is_single() && 'property' == get_post_type() ) {}` but that didn't work for me

Comment: @ChipBennett - I got it working on my custom post type, but the content disappears from any other post type. See edit above.

Comment: That's because you're not returning `$content` for post types other than for your custom post type. See updated answer.

Comment: Just a note - you don't need the else { } block - just the fallback return. If the condition is met, the return in the if() takes you out of the function, if you make it past the if() then the fallback return will hit.

Comment: True, the `return $content;` could be pulled out of the `if/else` conditional. I mainly put it where it is as an aid to understanding the logic of what gets returned, how, and why.

Comment: you can put the third argument for priority in the add_filter function.

Comment: Thanks for Edit 2 Hook. After a little work around, could be able to echo some shortcode after the content. Old post but working atm in WP 5.4. !!!

Answer (score 2):

There was a new hook introduced in 5.2 that triggers after the opening `<body>` tag. No more need to mess with the post content.

[wp_open_body](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_body_open/)

```
/**
 * Add code snippets directly after the opening <body> tag.
 */
function add_to_top_of_body() {
    echo '<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) --><noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-YOURMOM" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript><!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->';
}
add_action( 'wp_body_open', 'add_to_top_of_body' );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function property_slideshow( $content ) {
    if ( is_singular( 'property' ) ) {
        $custom_content = do_shortcode( '[portfolio_slideshow]' );
        $custom_content .= $content;
        }
        return $custom_content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'property_slideshow' );
```

The [`is_singular`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular) conditional tag checks if a singular post is being displayed and enables you to specify the $post_types parameter which in this case is property.

Also, you might want to look at [`do_shortcode`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode)

Comment: Late to the game here, but you're returning an empty variable in the instance that is_singular( 'property' ) returns false. If you invert your logic there, and simply return $content in that case, you will end up with cleaner, more readable code.

Comment: Could also add else or use a ternary operator. Its a quick example not fully tested which can be extended.