# Is there a way to include some external script to some or all pages in a wordpress site?

Tags: plugins, customization, scripts

My current requirement is to stick a countdown timer on the top of every page or on the side of all pages. But since i get too many requests like this, i was looking for a technique with which i can include some external javascript or jquery plugin or maybe some HTML code forced upon a particular location on some/all pages. Has anybody ever done this??

For my requirements, i have found some plugins for countdown timers but they would only create a sidebar or a post. What i had in mind that i would create a div with an iframe inside pointing to countdown page and will stick this div on the top of the page through CSS. But i wanna know if there is any standard way of doing such things.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to write a plugin or add to your theme's `functions.php` file a function to filter `the_content`.

There's already a good answer to this problem at [WordPress hooks/filters insert before content or after title](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39918/wordpress-hooks-filters-insert-before-content-or-after-title).